# iPhone 5s shows SIM Not Valid after sending it home from USA

Tags: iphone

I have bought an iPhone 5s from USA, and sent it back home, however it shows "SIM Not Valid". Is it factory locked, country locked or something else? How can I fix it?

Comment: Does the sim work for other devices?

Comment: i insert other sims in my mobile,it gives same error

Answer (score 2):

Depending on which model you bought in the US, you may or may not have a sim in the phone.

Sounds as though you have a sim, you will need to remove the US sim, buy a sim from a provider in the country where you are going to use it (or enable roaming - although it does not sound as if you are having a roaming issue).

---

You noted in your comments that you used other sims, if so then:

**YES, your phone is most probably locked to a US carrier.**

To answer your question how to fix it. You need to buy a non carrier locked phone from Apple in the US, or jail break your phone.

This site does not condone jail breaking however I can point you to a very good site called google which will help you out.

Comment: tell me, how to unlock it?Is there some way,i google it alot,but all methods are paid..!!!

Comment: keep googling. Cannot help you with unlocking it on this site.

Comment: just give me hint,i will handle it my-self

Comment: expand your search terms, use a different search engine like duckduckgo.com